# MySQL Select unique sorted field values

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I've trying to concatenate the values of 2 `GROUP_CONCAT( columns )` from a single table that's been joined twice, then get the unique items from the list.

I can do all this outside of my query but if possible it would be nice to just pull the data from the DB with a JOIN and some fancy string manipulation.

Simply put, I want to produce **1,2,3,4** from selecting **1,2,3** and **1,3,4**. The *1,2,3* adn *1,3,4* are the results of the GROUP_CONCAT on the twice joined table. I can get this far:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(
    ",",
    "1,2,3", 
    "1,3,4"
)
```

Which outputs **1,2,3,1,3,4**

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
-- NOTE TO SKIM READERS: THIS QUERY WILL NOT WORK
SELECT 
    SORT_LIST( 
        DISTINCT
        CONCAT_WS(
            ",",
            "1,2,3", 
            "1,3,4"
        )
    )
-- NOTE TO SKIM READERS: THIS QUERY WILL NOT WORK
```

But I can't find anything like that in MySQL.

The **1,2,3** and **1,3,4** have already been produced with `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT`col`)`

Comment: Do you have comma separated values in a single column? There are better ways of storing this data that would make this query more straightforward. Is that an option?

Comment: I'm joining to another table, that has values **A=1,B=2** and **B=1,A=2** in different rows. So I'm joining twice and selecting `CONCAT( A,B )` then `CONCAT( B,A )`, then `CONCAT` the results which is giving me "12,12". The *sort* aspect of the question is less important, it's really the *unique/distinct* aspect I need to work out

Comment: "1,2,3" and "1,3,4" are two string and they doesn't match, you want to treat them integer 1,2,3 and 1,3,4, that i think is not possible without writting a custom function.

Comment: Ok I've figured out a way around it, I'll have to fully select all rows in my 2 tables in a `UNION` within a subquery, and then join on an ID to limit them but it means I can use a `GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT... )` on the result of the subquery, which gives me what I want: http://pastebin.com/NTh2CfuD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment I worked out a way to achieve distinct concatenated lists of strings using a sub query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1234`;
CREATE TABLE `test1234` (
    `val` int(1),
    `type` varchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO `test1234` VALUES
( 1, 'a' ),
( 2, 'a' ),
( 3, 'a' ),
( 1, 'b' ),
( 3, 'b' ),
( 4, 'b' );

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `val` ) AS `vals`
FROM (
        (
                SELECT `val` FROM `test1234` WHERE `type` = 'a'
        ) UNION DISTINCT (
                SELECT `val` FROM `test1234` WHERE `type` = 'b'
        )
) AS `test`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1234`;
```

This selected **1,2,3,4**